# iOS - Use Objective C variables in C Code

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, core-audio

I'm doing some Core Audio programming in iOS, and have come to a situation where I need to use a variable that I declared in Objective C in some C callback code. 
The buffer variable has to be accessible by both Objective C and C syntaxes, but in the C syntax there is an error saying "Use of undeclared identifier buffer".

How do I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Pier.

The variable is buffer, declared as follows in RIORecoerdingViewController.h :

```
@interface RIORecoerdingViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioSessionDelegate> {
OSStatus status;
AudioComponentInstance audioUnit;

AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
RIO rio;

IBOutlet UIButton *button;
BOOL isPlaying;
Float64 graphSampleRate;

NSString *destinationFilePath;
CFURLRef destinationURL;
ExtAudioFileRef outExtAudioFile;

// New
AUGraph theGraph;
TPCircularBuffer buffer;
}
```

and I wish to use it in a C callback function

```
static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon, 
                              AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                              const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, 
                              UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                              UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                              AudioBufferList *ioData) {

if (rio->recording)
{   
    TPCircularBufferProduceBytes(&buffer, abl.mBuffers[0].mData, inNumberFrames * 2 * sizeof(SInt32)); //&buffer has an error "Use of undeclared identifier buffer"
}
return noErr;
    }
```

Comment: How about checking "Compile Sources As" under the target build settings of your app? It has some interesting options.

Comment: Not sure how this would help, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `void * inRefCon` argument in your `recordingCallback` is for. When you set up your RemoteIO callback, it probably looked something like this:

```
AURenderCallbackStruct callbackInfo;
callbackInfo.inputProc = &recordingCallback;
callbackInfo.inputProcRefCon = NULL;

AudioUnitSetProperty(rio,
                     kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                     0,
                     &callbackInfo,
                     sizeof(callbackInfo));
```

You can use the `inputProcRefCon` as an arbitrary pointer that will become the `inRefCon` pointer during your callback. If you just want to access one variable, it's easy (you just pass in the address of that variable). For example, if all you need's your TPCircularBuffer:

```
callbackInfo.inputProcRefCon = &buffer;
```

Then when your `recordingCallback` is called, you can access your buffer via the `inRefCon` arg as such:

```
TPCircularBuffer * bufferPtr = (TPCircularBuffer *)inRefCon;
TPCircularBufferProduceBytes(bufferPtr, abl.mBuffers[0].mData, inNumberFrames * 2 * sizeof(SInt32));
```

If you need access to more variables (like that `recording` boolean) you can make a struct and pass the address of that in instead.

Word on the street is that you should avoid Objective-C calls in your AURenderCallbacks (due to messaging overhead), but I don't have any hard data at the moment to back that up. You could pass `self` as the `inputProcRefCon`, but YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, one question, putting the TPCircularBuffer in a struct that's tied to callbackInfo.inputProcRefCon , is it going to be expensive? The recording and playback callbacks in my application are both going to use this buffer.

Comment: No, putting it in a struct and passing inRefProcCon a pointer to that struct is basically free (it's not going to copy the whole buffer, just the pointer to it, which is basically just a number).

Answer (score 2):

Your `buffer` variable is an instance variable of a concrete `RIORecoerdingViewController` instance. It doesn't make sense to use it without an instance ("which object does the buffer belong to?").

So if you have an instance, you can reference the ivar as usual (i.e. `yourRecoerdingViewController->buffer` if you want to go the C pointer route).

Comment: +1, but you have to make the ivar explicitly `@public`, since ivars are `@protected` by default and this won't compile.

Comment: @H2CO3 Agreed. I'd prefer access via a new property anyway. :)

Comment: It makes perfect sense if the RIORecoerdingViewController is guaranteed (by the app's design) to be a persistent singleton.

Comment: Even in case of a singleton it's a member of that very instance, so the code as it stands doesn't make sense. I wasn't saying that it might not be appropriate to store the pointer in a global variable or struct.

Comment: Thanks guys, I decided to go with Hotpaw2 and admsyn's solutions below. Appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Objective C is a pure superset of plain C.  It allows you to copy object and instance variable pointers into standard C global variables, parameter variables and structs (etc.)

One (considered ugly) possibility is to just copy your buffer pointer into a C global variable (and make sure to manually null it, or not use it when the buffer is released).  Then access it from anywhere, any C function.

Other (perhaps more elegant) possibilities include copying the buffer pointer into a struct that you pass to the C callback, or to pass a pointer to the object itself directly to, or via a struct element, to the C callback.  You can then use the "->" syntax from a C function in a .m file to access any instance variable of any object passed to a standard C function, such as an audio unit callback.  (The C function has to be declared inside a .m file so that the Objective C interface for the object definition can be imported.)

Yet another possibility, but inappropriate for audio callbacks, is to have the C function (in a .m file) message a singleton model object to get/set model object state (including buffer pointers).

Comment: Thanks for listing all the possibilities here, it was very informative.